# JAAS with grizzly websockets does not work

Tags: glassfish-3, roles, jaas, grizzly, j-security-check

Why doesn't @RolesAllowed of JAAS work i.e. why there is no exception when an unauthorized websocket request comes to the server. If the same request is an ajax request it works perfectly!

I am using grizzly websockets and glassfish server.

Answer (score 0):

In Glassfish3 WebSocket requests come to user WebSocketApplication directly bypassing web container. I think this is the reason why @RolesAllowed is ignored. You can try Glassfish4 + standard WebSocket API, I think @RolesAllowed should work there.